# Custom batches for tf.data.Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator, batchsize

I'm using the Estimator API of tensorflow and would like to create custom batches for training.

I have examples that looks as follows

```
example1 = {
   "num_sentences": 3,
   "sentences": [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]] 
}
example2 = {
   "num_sentences": 2,
   "sentences": [[1, 2], [3, 4]] 
}
```

So an example can have any number of fixed sized sentences. Now I would like to build batches which size depends on the number of sentences in a batch. Otherwise I have to use batch size 1 as some examples may have "batch size" sentences and a large batch size does not fit into the GPU-memory.

For example: I have a batch size of 6 and examples with the number of sentences [5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]. Then I group the examples to the batches [5], [3, 3] and [2, 2, 1]. Note that example "1" in the last batch would be padded.

I have written an algorithm that groups the examples to such batches. Now I am not able to feed the batches into tf.data.Dataset.

I have tried using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` but the method seems to expect individual examples and I get an error if the generator yields batches like [example1, example2].

How can I feed Dataset with custom batches? Is there a more elegant way to solve my problem?

Update: I assume I am not able to provide the output shapes parameter correctly. The following code works fine.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def gen():
    for b in range(3):
        #yield [{"num_sentences": 3, "sentences": [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]}]
        yield {"num_sentences": 3, "sentences": [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]}


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=gen, 
                                         output_types={'num_sentences': tf.int32, 'sentences': tf.int32},
                                         #output_shapes=tf.TensorShape([None,  {'num_sentences': tf.TensorShape(None), 'sentences': tf.TensorShape(None)}])
                                         output_shapes={'num_sentences': tf.TensorShape(None), 'sentences': tf.TensorShape(None)}
                                        )

def print_dataset(dataset):
    it = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(dataset.output_shapes)
        print(dataset.output_types)
        while True:
            try:
                data = it.get_next()
                print("data" + str(sess.run(data)))
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break

print_dataset(dataset)
```

If I yield an array instead and uncomment the output_shapes I get an error "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'
"

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121347/tensorflow-dataset-from-generator-with-variable-batch-size

Comment: thanks for the link. It seems like that it should be possible to provide custom batches. As I am using dictionaries I am not able to figure out how to provide the output_shapes parameter. See the edited post above.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out how to solve the above problem. I think I have to merge the examples into "one" dictionary.

```
# a batch with two examples each with sentence size 3
yield {"num_sentences": [3, 3], "sentences": [[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]]}
```