# Optimize and batch byte file data into keras models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

I'm trying to feed my model.fit with chunked data since my entire dataset doesn't fit my memory.
TF version is 2.4.

I've optimized dataset stored in file saving it in byte, each col is 1 byte (0-255) but now I need to read it in chunk and start learning process of my network.

Before this I was using .csv, loading dataset with numpy reshape and then give entire dataset to keras model.

Should I use`.fit` for each chunk I load with `load_weight` from previus iteration?

Comment: When data does not fit into the memory, one usually uses [TF datasets generators](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator). The generator allows to load data step by step. Have you considered this?

Comment: I will take a look, thx for the info

Comment: @IvanK. I read about TF dataset generators, but I can't find a tutorial on how load a bynary data. I've a function that can recreate correctly my dataset from that file, but it read all file, from start to end. There is a way to use the same function that load data partially each batch_size/bytes ecc?

Comment: Can you turn your function to be a generator? That is, while reading the whole file produce data sample by sample (using python `yield`)?

Comment: I don't know if I can change it to be a generator. Actually I use open('file') and then iterate with a while True, when the read fails I stop it.

Comment: This is almos a generator. I will eleborate on what you should do to make it work later today.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot for your help. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121347/tensorflow-dataset-from-generator-with-variable-batch-size/52126464) that has a similar problem like mine, he uses HDF5 file insetead a pure binary, and it uses each row as sample instead of 5 row as a sample (LSTM model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `file` be the file, in which you store the data. To create a dataset, one first needs to create a `generator` for reading the data. Schematically, it should have the following structure:

```
    def generator(file):
        with open(file,'r') as f:
            for linne in f:
                ### code for generating single sample and, optionally, label ###
                yield (sample,label)
```

You do not to signal anyhow the end of the file. When `generator` is called, it yields all data in the form of pairs `(sample,label)`.  To check that `generator` correctly produces data, one may do something like

```
    for (sample,label) in generator(file):
        ### examine your samples and labels
```

If in order to produce a single sample you need to process more then one line in the `file`, you should modify the code (or the file) accordingly.

Once you have a working generator, you can create a `dataset`:

```
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator( generator(file), 
                output_signature=( 
                    ( tf.TensorSpec(shape=(shape-of-your-data)),
                      tf.TensorSpec(shape=(shape-of-your-labels)) ) )
```

You can read samples and labels from different files. If `dataset_A` and `dataset_B` contain samples and labels respectively, you need to use `zip` method of datasets to get dataset yielding data in form of the training pairs.

Further, you need to makes batches out of individual samples:

```
    dataset = dataset.batch(32)
```

To improve the pipeline for preparing the data, it is good practice to `prefetch` the dataset:

```
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(number-of-batches-to-prefetch)
```

This "prerads" the data while the current data is passed though the network, see [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance) for details (I do not recomend using `tf.data.AUTOTUNE` as an argument for `prefetch`; usually manually set parameter yields better performance).

The resulting `dataset` can be used for fitting the model in `model.fit`. Note that for datasets the `shuffle` parameter of `model.fit` is ignored. To shuffle your data you need to use `shuffle` method of `datasets`.

Personally, I found it usefull generate data from `h5` files. In this case you just need to iterate over samples like in numpy array, insted of reading file line by file. This is more flexible (for example, you can shuffle you data directly in the generator) and more convinient in terms of reading the data.

Comment: Thx man, using your help I manage to create my dataset with yield, the dataset is the same if I load entire in memory or from this new generator. But I've some error on fit.
1) is slower (from 25s to 60s), but I think is due to generation on the fly
2) I go in overfitting, if use fit with old all in memory dataset I get f1_score of 0.8, with generator I get 0.14 and loss goes to 0 and accuracy to 1, after 1 epoch

Comment: Yes, fitting becomes slower due to reading data on the fly. You can try to optimize the time by: 1) experimenting with `prefetch` parameter of the dataset. In particluar, `tf.data.AUTOTUNE` sometimes yields good performance. 2) After prefetching the dataset, you may try to cache it: `dataset = dataset.cache()`, and, possible, prefetch it again. See [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache) for important nuances.

Comment: Regarding the second problem, I had a similar issue once. In my case this was due to the fact that the dataset was not shuffled, so that all samples from the same class were going after each other. After implemeting shuffling in the generator, the problem was gone. To understand whether you have the same problem: 1) examine generated labels explicitly and 2) check model accuracy on separate validation set (make sure it does not intersects with the training one; was accuracy of `1` for the validation set?).

Comment: If the problem is indeed with shuffling, there are two possible ways to solve the problem. The first is to make data in the file already shuffled. The (small) drawback of this method is that batches and their ordering will be the same for all epoches. The second way is to implement shuffling in the generator. I doubt that this can be implemented if you generator reads data line by line from the file, but for `.h5' files this is not a big problem.

Comment: I see, with prefetch I get a little improvement, I will try cache too. For second problem maybe is like you said, an ordering problem. I need to understand how write an H5 file with dataset so I can shuffle it.

Comment: I found my problem (maybe). Since my binary file has label as string, when load entire dataset in memory `to_categorical` can generate label array correctly. With generator, since I load sample by sample `to_categorical` always generate the same multiclass label [1, 0 ,0 ,0 ...] (due to same class string seen by function). I use this tecnique due to not linear ID label (1,2,3,6,8,9 etc.). I need to generate label correctly for each sample